# Capistrano deployment to aws- rake aborted and rake db:migrate failed SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano3

**Can anyone help me debug this?**

```
  INFO [ff29ccac] Finished in 0.574 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  ** Invoke deploy:normalize_assets (first_time)
  ** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
  ** Execute deploy:normalize_assets
  ** Invoke deploy:migrate (first_time)
  ** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
  ** Execute deploy:migrate
  INFO [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
  DEBUG [a94a32ed] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905'" 1>&2; false; fi as ubuntu@52.88.201.58
  DEBUG [a94a32ed] Command: if test ! -d /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905'" 1>&2; false; fi
  DEBUG [a94a32ed] Finished in 0.579 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [34447532] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate as ubuntu@52.88.201.58
  DEBUG [34447532] Command: cd /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 RAILS_ENV=production RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate )
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:148: warning: circular argument reference - filters
  DEBUG [34447532]  WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
  DEBUG [34447532]  
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.22.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:43: warning: duplicated key at line 81 ignored: "name"
  DEBUG [34447532]  rake aborted!
  DEBUG [34447532]  (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  DEBUG [34447532]  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
  DEBUG [34447532]  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
  DEBUG [34447532]  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  cap aborted!
  SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@52.88.201.58: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: Nothing written
  rake stderr: /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:148: warning: circular argument reference - filters
  WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.22.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:43: warning: duplicated key at line 81 ignored: "name"
  rake aborted!
  (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
  SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: Nothing written
  rake stderr: /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:148: warning: circular argument reference - filters
  WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.22.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:43: warning: duplicated key at line 81 ignored: "name"
  rake aborted!
  (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
  /home/gaurav/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
  Tasks: TOP => deploy:migrate
  The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@52.88.201.58: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: Nothing written
  rake stderr: /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.22.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:148: warning: circular argument reference - filters
  WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.22.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:43: warning: duplicated key at line 81 ignored: "name"
  rake aborted!
  (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//releases/20150925105905/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  /home/ubuntu/apps//shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  >
  ** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
  ** Execute deploy:failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem fog with

`gem 'fog', '1.23.0'`

[Check this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909681/duplicated-key-at-line-80-ignored-name-rvm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild Nokogiri. Log into the server and run `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`. You will probably need to specify the version of Nokogiri you want installed. Upgrade it if possible with `bundle update nokogiri`. Check out the [debugging information on Nokogiri's website](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html).